# Using firebase-functions-test with emulator

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to create an automated test for my CI, connecting my cloud functions with the local emulator. I am using firebase-functions-test along with the firebase-admin sdk. While my tests pass locally they fail when using the test docker container. I've created a test to illustrate.

```js
const databaseName = 'foo';
const test = require('firebase-functions-test')({
  databaseURL: "http://localhost:9000?ns=" + databaseName
});
describe('test', () => {
  it('tests', async () => {
    const admin = require('firebase-admin')
    admin.initializeApp();
    return await admin.database().ref('bar').push('baz')
  })
})
```

The test above throws repeated warnings:

```
@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal metadata.google.internal:80. Error code: ENOTFOUND\"."}
```

I suspect it has something to do with `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`, but I don't really understand why the emulator would check for gcloud credentials.

Any advice is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Were you able to find the solution for this? I'm trying to do the same, but my testing function keeps using the production Firebase instead of the emulator